# dmesg gives PM-Timer Bug

Tags: boot, dmesg

Command `dmesg` on my PC gives e.g. following:

```
[    0.123440] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [8086:24c0] type 0 class 0x000601
[    0.123446] * The chipset may have PM-Timer Bug. Due to workarounds for a bug,
[    0.123447] * this clock source is slow. If you are sure your timer does not have
[    0.123449] * this bug, please use "acpi_pm_good" to disable the workaround
[    0.123544] pci 0000:00:1f.1: [8086:24cb] type 0 class 0x000101
```

What does it mean?

Chipset is an old Intel 845GL/GV / Intel® ICH4

Answer (score 0):

It means that your LPC device is old and contains a bug in the PM-Timer (most commonly known as "High Precision Event Time"). I wouldn't bother with it:

> The Low Pin Count bus, or **LPC** bus, is used on IBM-compatible personal computers to connect low-bandwidth devices to the CPU, such as the boot ROM and the "legacy" I/O devices (behind a super I/O chip). The "legacy" I/O devices usually include **serial and parallel ports, PS/2 keyboard, PS/2 mouse, floppy disk controller and—more recently—the Trusted Platform Module (TPM)**. The physical wires of the LPC bus usually connect to the southbridge chip on a PC motherboard, which contains the circuit equivalents of the "legacy" onboard peripherals of the IBM PC/AT architecture, such as the two programmable interrupt controllers, the programmable interval timer, and the two ISA DMA controllers.

Unless your TPM requires it and/or your system is giving you headaches related with any of those devices I wouldn't touch it.